# Custom task runner method throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, argumentexception

Because of the fact that CultureInfo is not being copied from thread to thread I have made following method to do that thing for me.

```
public static StartCustomTask(Action action, TaskCreationOptions tco = TaskCreationOptions.None)
{
    var currentCult = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCuture;
    var currentUiCult = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCuture = currentCult;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUiCult;
        action();
    }, tco);
}
```

basically this code copies culture info from current thread to the thread that is gonna execute the `action`. I don't know why but it throws `System.ArgumentException` saying `Value does not fall within the expected range`. I've tried to run the action itself regularly on the main thread and it goes perfectly. By that I mean, that method that is being an action does not have a problem itself there is a problem somewhere in the code above I guess.

here is the stack trace of an exception

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.BuildUrl(Func`1 pathAccessor)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Url()
   at SL.CoreLogic.Web.FrontEnd.Controllers.AccountController.<>c__DisplayClass37.<ResetPassword>b__31() in d:\CoreProjects\CoreLogic\CoreLogic-RusSlot\SL.CoreLogic\SL.CoreLogic.Web.FrontEnd\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 447
   at SL.CoreLogic.Common.CustomTask.<>c__DisplayClass1.<StartWithCurrentCulture>b__0() in d:\CoreProjects\CoreLogic\CoreLogic-RusSlot\SL.CoreLogic\SL.CoreLogic.Common\CustomTask.cs:line 22
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.
```

and one more thing. this code was working perfectly but all of a sudden it started doing this.

Comment: I don't see the problem, it's working for me. What is in the action you are passing in?

Comment: it is an anonymus method of type Action () => doThing(new Obj{ //configure properties })) looks like this if i run just this doThing(new Obj{ //configure properties })) it works okay but if I pass this one to that method as an action that it starts to do this weird thing

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: on lines which contain this statement () => doThing(new Obj{ //configure properties }))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. the problem was that the action contained a line like this Url = Request.Url, as I guess at the time code was being executed the Request object did not exist or was not set.